# Why have a 'static' definition in a function?

Tags: c, static

Considering the example at http://c-faq.com/misc/hexio.html, what is the reason to have an additional pointer to a 'static' character buffer? Why can't we get away with `retbuf`?

Comment: Are you asking why we need the `static` keyword, or why there is a pointer `char* p` pointing to `retbuf`?

Answer (score 3):

Without the `static` keyword, the buffer would be allocated on the stack -- and deallocated by the time the function returns to the caller.

Using `static` ensures the buffer is valid after the function returns.

Comment: I thought he was asking why `p` was needed, rather than just `retbuf`.

Comment: Yes, the question is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You need a pointer so you can store a changing address.  If you just had `retbuf`, you would have to design the function to use a changing index variable.  E.g.:

```
int ind = sizeof(retbuf)-1;
retbuf[ind] = '\0';
```

etc.

Note that arrays are not pointers.  An array is a fixed-size region of memory.  A pointer is an address.

Comment: Thanks for input, but I still don't get it completely. Consider this snippet form the link above:

static char retbuf[33];
char *p;
p = &retbuf[sizeof(retbuf)-1];


Why do we need to keep additional pointer 'p' to a 'retbuf'?  If we fill in the 'retbuf' and then return it from the function ('return retbuf'), it will always point at the very first element of the buffer, am I wrong here?

Comment: @Mark, first, `p` does not always end up equal to `retbuf`'s first element at the end of the function.  As a simple example, if `num` is 0, `p` will stay equal to `retbuf + sizeof(retbuf) - 1`.  Second, p is used *during* the function to keep track of which location to write to.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I should have been more careful when looking at the code. Thank you Matthew!